# disable right click on a link in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

How to disable right click on a link in visualforce? I am calling the field in a object using select query where it is a lookup. So I provided onclick ="return false" but the link can still be opened with a right click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

for this alongside your current code? Although it could be undone by someone in the browser bar using

```
javascript:void oncontextmenu(null)
```

or by just viewing the source of the page. I would imagine that 99% of users won't go through those hoops though.

It should also disable right click through the entire page which may be undesirable.

Paul